# automatic initiation of service through broadcast receiver

Tags: android, service, broadcast

I start a service using alarm manager using button click. It is working too. I have done it this way:

```
    Intent scheduleSMS = new Intent(SMSProjectDatabase.this,SendSMS.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(SMSProjectDatabase.this,0, scheduleSMS,0);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    calendar.add(Calendar.SECOND,(int)GeneralUtil.calculateTimeDifference(getApplicationContext()));
    Log.i("SMS is scheduled after ",""+GeneralUtil.calculateTimeDifference(getApplicationContext()));

    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
```

Here SendSMS is a service that will be started by the alarm manager. But this is not how i want to start a service in my code. I want to Use the Alarmmanager to trigger a broadcast for the Broadcastreceiver. The Broadcastreceiver then starts the Service for me.

My BroadCast Receiver is

public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    //here i want to start the service through the alarm manager

}
```

}

But i donno how am i supposed to do this.Please provide the appropriate solution for me to solve this problelm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just simply need to put your stuff for calling `Service` using `AlarmManager` inside the `onReceive()`

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
  // To get AlarmManager instance working you can use Context arg0
  AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) 
                                           arg0.getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE); 
  // put your stuff to start Service using AlarmManager
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use  registerReceiver() function .
But y you want alaram mansger to trigger broadcast. Broadcastreceiver is used to receive broadcast when something is broadcast to the application.